# Why im getting this error when i run my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting this error when i run my android app, any advice to fix it plz?

### Error:

> 10-12 23:05:20.472 29607-29607/com.example.med E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.med, PID: 29607
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.med/com.example.med.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.example.med.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  10-12 23:09:56.627 29899-29899/com.example.med/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.med, PID: 29899
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.med/com.example.med.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.example.med.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

### MainActivity:

```
package com.example.med;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            view.performClick();
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private Button playButton;
    private Button lessonButton;
    private Button settingsButton;
    private Button highscoresButton;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                startGameSettings();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_highscores:
                startHighScore();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_playagain:
                startGameplay();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_layout_controls);

        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });


        playButton =findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        lessonButton = findViewById(R.id.lessonButton);
        settingsButton = findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        highscoresButton = findViewById(R.id.highscoresButton);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        lessonButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        highscoresButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mVisible = false;
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.playButton){
            startGameplay();

        }else if (view.getId() == R.id.lessonButton){
            startLessonaMenu();
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.settingsButton){
            startGameSettings();
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.highscoresButton){
            startHighScore();
        }
    }

    public void startLessonaMenu() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LessonsMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void startHighScore() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HighScore.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void startGameSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameSettings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void startGameplay() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gameplay.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your MainActivity code plz!

Comment: You can see the issue in the stacktrace:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.med.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
in line 104 of MainActivity.java, you are using something that has a value of null

Comment: Null Pointer Exception it says. After setting the layout, you might be trying to access something in the layout which might not be present.

Comment: I posted  MainActivity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to initialize your `mContentView` before using it :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_layout_controls);

        mContentView= findViewById(R.id.mContentView); \\******

        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`mContentView` is never assigned anywhere. There is your NPE.